# email reports at scheduled time

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, scheduling

I am working on a large asp.net website at the moment. I would like to schedule some reports  and email them weekly/monthly to my customers. I am thinking of using a windows service and use a timer. Is this the best option?

Comment: You tagged this with Reporting Services(SSRS.) Do you have SSRS installed? It provides functionality for this, but I'm not sure if you are interested in that as an option. If you've already got an SSRS instance installed, then use this, otherwise, it might not be worth it, and you can roll your own...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io)

> Description from http://hangfire.io «
>   An easy way to perform fire-and-forget, delayed and recurring tasks
>   inside ASP.NET applications. No Windows Service required. Backed by
>   persistent storages. Open and free for commercial use. »

It let's you schedule a task like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MyReport.Run(), Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Where `MyReport.Run()` is a static method that takes care of rendering and emailing the report.

Answer (score 1):

I think a windows service is the best option, although I wouldn't personally use a timer.

The way we handle this is to have the main service work loop idle for 1/2 second, then check to see if any reports need to be run.

One very important consideration in this design: in order to prevent a single report from crashing your service, you should do a couple of things:

1) Run all reports in separate threads (use backgroudworker or manage your own threads).

2) Only start a certain number of reports at a time. In your loop, keep track of the reports that are running and when one stops, start the next one. The maximum number will depend on the intensity of the reports and the capacity of your server.